# Scrollbar inaccesible tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
window.title("Password Vault")
w_window = 750
h_window = 550
pos_right = round(window.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - w_window / 2)
pos_down = round(window.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - h_window / 2)

window.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(w_window, h_window, pos_right, pos_down))
window['background'] = color['black']
window.resizable(False, False)

frame = Frame(window,width=500,height=400)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
canvas=Canvas(frame,bg=color['black'],width=500,height=400)
vertibar=Scrollbar( frame,orient=VERTICAL)
vertibar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
vertibar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vertibar.set)
```

I am trying to make a password vault in Python with a scrollbar, but I am encountering the following problem:

**The scrollbar widget is present but inaccessible.**

Libraries used:

- sqlite3
- hashlib
- tkinter
- customtkinter
- partial
- uuid
- pyperclip
- base64
- cryptography

Python version: **3.10.0**

Comment: You did not set the `scrollregion` of `canvas`.